# How to add a fragment to a page's content in SAPUI5

Tags: view, sapui5

I would like to add a dynamically created fragment to a page's content inside the view's controller.
I currently have the following code:

```
    if(this.tableFragment) {
        this.tableFragment.destroy(true);
    }
    this.tableFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("com.example.app.view.fragments.FragmentName");

    this.getView().byId("pageID").addDependent(this.tableFragment);
```

and would like to insert it into a page:

```
<Page id="pageID" title="Page Title" class="sapUiStdPage">                  
    <content>

    </content>
</Page>
```

but I get an error that contains the following:
`is not valid for aggregation "dependents" of Element`

I also get the error:
`this.tableFragment.destroy is not a function`

Comment: `this.byId("pageID").addContent(this.tableFragment);`

Comment: That gives this error: `is not valid for aggregation "content" of Element` @Marc

Comment: Then pls show the content of your fragment.

Comment: It’s a smart table. It works perfectly fine if I add the fragment manually.